# How do I allow my NSTableView delegate/datasource handle copy/paste/etc

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nspasteboard

I have an `NSTableView` where I'd like to be able to highlight 1 or more rows, and then hit the `delete` key to delete them, or hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy them to the pasteboard.

I've found a suggestion to subclass the NSTableView and then code up a method for

`-(void)copy:(id)sender`

The documentation says that subclassing the `NSTableView` is rarely necessary.  Instead, use the dataSource or delegate, or subclass a subcomponent.  The delegate and dataSource protocols don't handle menu commands or keyboard short cuts.  If I try to subclass anyways, I run into a problem where the subclass needs to send a message to the delegate, but my custom methods aren't part of the protocol, so the compiler complains. Rather than fight the design pattern, I'd rather know what the "correct" approach to this problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by declaring the `NSTableView`'s parent window's delegate as the `NSTableView`'s controller (which is also its `dataSource` and `delegate`).  Now it receives menu actions as part of the responder chain.

Comment: Could you explain what you did? What do you mean by the `NSTableView`'s _"controller"_?

Comment: Its been long enough I don't remember the details.  But the `NSTableView` is a view, which is the MVC architecture is controlled through a controller class.  So whichever controller "owns" the `NSTableView` is the one I'm referring to

Comment: I see, thanks! I went to subclassing though, works as a charm for me!